# How do I map the count of images in a ImageCollection in GEE?

Tags: gis, google-earth-engine

I want to replicate the following image, which pixel-wise tells (look at the legend) how many images are available in a ee.ImageCollection.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgoMR.png [1]

I thank you for any help in advance!

References:
[1] Masoud Mahdianpari, Bahram Salehi, Fariba Mohammadimanesh,
Brian Brisco, Saeid Homayouni, Eric Gill, Evan R. DeLancey & Laura Bourgeau-Chavez
(2020) Big Data for a Big Country: The First Generation of Canadian Wetland Inventory Map
at a Spatial Resolution of 10-m Using Sentinel-1 and Sentinel-2 Data on the Google Earth
Engine Cloud Computing Platform, Canadian Journal of Remote Sensing, 46:1, 15-33, DOI:
10.1080/07038992.2019.1711366[enter image description here]

Answer (score 0):

If you use `geemap` Python package you can use `geemap.image_count` function and `Map.add_colorbar` method to add a colorbar. If you use JavaScript code editor you  could use the code below which is derived and modified from geemap [repo](https://github.com/giswqs/geemap/blob/master/geemap/common.py) and you could check [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/307652/how-to-add-color-map-scale-in-google-earth-engine) out for adding a colorbar:

```js
// Acquire Sentinel-2 Image Collection
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED')

// Get one band's name
var band = collection.first().bandNames().get(0)

// Generate desired image where each pixel value represents the number of Images in the Image Collection
var image = collection.filterBounds(geometry)
                      .filterDate('2017-01-01', '2020-04-15')
                      .filter(ee.Filter.listContains("system:band_names", band))
                      .select([band])
                      .reduce(ee.Reducer.count())
                      .clip(geometry)
var vis = {"min":0,"max":900,"palette":["00FFFF","0000FF"]}
Map.addLayer(image, vis, 'NDWI')
```